# Selection Callback for text input

Tags: matlab, callback, textbox, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

I'm using MATLAB GUIDE to build a GUI to control a piece of hardware. I have a data table the user needs to fill, and every time they select a cell a new configuration is sent to the hardware. This is easily done using the `CellSelectionCallback()`.

However, I also have a single reference value that is currently being entered into an `edit` textbox. I would like for the GUI to send a new configuration to the hardware whenever a user selects the textbox, but before they enter their new value. Is there a similar `SelectionCallback` function that can be used for the textbox? The best solution I've come up with is to create a 1x1 table instead of an edit box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is going to be to use a Java control since the standard MATLAB `uicontrol` does not have a focus callback. You can use a `JTextField` object, add it to your GUI with [`javacomponent`](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/javacomponent) and then register the `FocusGainedCallback`.

```matlab
jtext = javax.swing.JTextField();
jtext.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.JTextField.CENTER);

% Add the control to your GUI
htext = javacomponent(jtext, [10 10 200 10]);

% Register a callback to be executed when the box is selected
set(htext, 'FocusGainedCallback', @yourCallback)
```